# Mapping State Borders ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, projection, shapefile

Im trying to map state boundaries to a raster (showing elevation) in ggplot. I get an interesting error that I cannot overcome when adding my `geom_polygon`

```
 dir=("YOUR DIR")
library (tidyverse)
library (raster)
library (rasterVis)
library (rgeos)
require ("maps")
usa2 <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)
counties<- c("El Paso","Jeff Davis","Culberson", "Hudspeth", "Persidio", "Brewster", "Pecos", "Loving", "Winkler", "Ward", "Lea", "Eddy", "Chaves", "Lincoln","Otero", "Dona Ana", "Socorro", "Sierra", "Luna", "Catron", "Grant", "Hidalgo", "Cochise", "Greenlee", "Graham", "Gila", "Pinal", "Pima", "Santa Cruz")
usa2 <- subset(usa2,NAME_2 %in% counties)

usa2c <- gCentroid(usa2) %>% coordinates()

dem2 <- getData("SRTM",lat=usa2c[2],lon=usa2c[1],path=dir)
dem=dem2
dem <- crop(dem,usa2,filename=file.path(dir,"dem_usa2.tif"))

# reduce raster resolution
dem_lower_res<- aggregate(dem, fact=10)

dem.p  <-  rasterToPoints(dem_lower_res )
df <-  data.frame(dem.p)
colnames(df) = c("lon", "lat", "alt")


state<-getData("GADM", country="USA", level=2)
st.names<- c("Texas", "New Mexico", "Arizona")
state2<-subset(state,NAME_1 %in% st.names) %>% subset (NAME_2 %in% counties)
st.gg<- fortify(state2)

usa2 <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(lon,lat)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = alt)) + scale_fill_distiller(palette="BrBG") + theme_dark() +    
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + geom_path (aes (st.gg$long, st.gg$lat, group=st.gg$group))
p2
```

[image: shapefile of counties of interest]
[image: raster of altitude]
The error: is
`Error: mapping must be created by aes()`

after a suggestion I think we are closer: 
[image: e]

Comment: lat and long are not aesthetics in the geom_polygon function. I think you will need to use `x = long, y = lat`

Comment: I tried that but no luck

Comment: I haven't been able to run your code. Please update it to make sure it includes all packages and variables. The best way to check is to copy and paste the code into a new r session. Even better though would be if you could use a more simple example since plotting is the issue there should be no need for people to download a bunch of data to help solve your problem

Comment: what does `group = group` refer to in your `geom_polygon` call?

Comment: @see24 Ive edited the file to list all dependent packages

Comment: looks like there are still some projection issues to work out, but adjust your `geom_path` layer to this: `geom_path(data = st.gg, aes(x = long, y = lat, group= group))` and you can get rid of the error

Comment: Thanks @Nate. Do you mean that the rater and the shapfile are not in the same projection?

Comment: Just that they were not overlaying in the final plot when I reproduced. No warnings or errors, but the raster was sitting above the path outline of the counties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the SRTM data to work so I used `name = "alt"` which worked much better. 
I also used the sf package and `geom_sf` since it makes things easier

```
dir=(getwd())
library (tidyverse)
library (raster)
library (rasterVis)
library (rgeos)
library(sf)
require ("maps")
usa2 <- getData('GADM', country='USA', level=2)
counties<- c("El Paso","Jeff Davis","Culberson", "Hudspeth", "Persidio", "Brewster",
"Pecos", "Loving", "Winkler", "Ward", "Lea", "Eddy", "Chaves", "Lincoln","Otero",
"Dona Ana", "Socorro", "Sierra", "Luna", "Catron", "Grant", "Hidalgo", "Cochise", 
"Greenlee", "Graham", "Gila", "Pinal", "Pima", "Santa Cruz")

usa2 <- subset(usa2,NAME_2 %in% counties)

state<-getData("GADM", country="USA", level=2)
st.names<- c("Texas", "New Mexico", "Arizona")
state2<-subset(state,NAME_1 %in% st.names) %>% subset (NAME_2 %in% counties)

dem2 <- getData("alt", country = "USA")
dem=dem2
dem <- crop(dem[[1]], state2, filename=file.path(dir,"dem_usa2.tif"), overwrite = TRUE)

# reduce raster resolution
dem_lower_res<- aggregate(dem, fact=10)

dem.p  <-  rasterToPoints(dem_lower_res )
df <-  data.frame(dem.p)
colnames(df) = c("lon", "lat", "alt")

state3 <- sf::st_as_sf(state2)

p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(lon,lat)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = alt)) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="BrBG") + 
  theme_dark() +    
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  geom_sf(data = state3, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = NA)
p2
```

Comment: This looks solid. Its a bit grainy so I may decide to remove aggregate. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove Hidalgo County (TX)  but not Hidalgo Co (NM) from the shape file?

Comment: `usa2 <- subset(usa2,NAME_2 %in% counties) %>% filter (NAME1!='Texas' & NAME2!='Hidalgo')` This is what I have tried so far @see24

Comment: I cheated and just removed Hidalgo county from both NM and TX but the map looks much better.

Comment: once it is an `sf` object after `st_as_sf` it is the same as any data frame so you can remove the row for "Hidalgo County" using whatever method you like for subsetting a dataframe. I would use `dplyr::filter(!(NAME_2 == "Hidalgo" & NAME_1 == "Texas"))`